# sheer dipping bliss -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Usage example with a context:

> When the occasion arises that you need a dip, be it for chips, crudités or crusty bread, think outside the box and head for the freezer. TJ’s Creamy Spinach & Artichoke Dip (which, to be clear, does come in a box) is our version of the restaurant favorite.
>   And thanks to one of the miracles of modern culinary science—the deep freeze—it goes from freezer to microwave to **sheer dipping bliss** in less than 5 minutes. Versatile, delicious and incredibly convenient—a winning combination! We’re selling each 8.8 ounce package for $2.99—you’ll find it in our freezers.

What does **sheer dipping bliss** mean?

Comment: I recommend trying dictionaries for *sheer*, *dip*, and *bliss* first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To* in this context is not identifying the next word as an infinitive.  *To* is used to describe a range of some sort - the word or phrase after "to" being the "upper limit" of the range.

> Everyone took 5 to 10 items for themselves.
>
> A comfortable temperature for most is 68 to 72 degrees Farhenheit.

Of course, the points in the range don't have to be terribly specific (i.e. they don't have to be a specific number ) and you can identify multiple "points" in the range with additional "to ..." phrases

> The weather has been crazy today.  It's gone from freezing to windy to humid all in one day.

So, the writer here, in making this sound more exciting, has used imagery-rich terms to describe the states of a process of cooking TJ’s Creamy Spinach & Artichoke Dip.

> it goes from freezer to microwave to sheer dipping bliss in less than 5 minutes.

we are talking about stages in the process of cooking the artichoke dip - that taking it from the freezer, to the microwave, to the final cooked state where it would become "sheer dipping bliss" will take less than 5 minutes.

Notice how this whole construct usually starts with "from" - that's your hint that a range is being talked about.

Answer (score 0):

Dip is a kind of blended paste in which food items (celery, chips, pieces of toasted bread, etc) are dipped.

Sheer bliss = "total pleasure"

*Sheer dipping bliss* is ad-speak for the unmitigated pleasure of consuming dip.

Compare: "for your *reading pleasure*" -- i.e. something you will find pleasurable to read.

For your *traveling needs*"  -- the needs you typically have when traveling.